# sudo apt-get update doesn't work on Linux Parrot

Tags: apt

running `sudo apt-get update` returns:

```
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

the whole terminal output looks like:

```
Err:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  Something wicked happened resolving 'download.sublimetext.com:https' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err:3 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot InRelease                         
  Something wicked happened resolving 'deb.parrotsec.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.microsoft.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/dists/parrot/InRelease  Something wicked happened resolving 'deb.parrotsec.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W: Failed to fetch https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease  Something wicked happened resolving 'download.sublimetext.com:https' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.microsoft.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having trouble resolving the hostnames into IP addresses. Probably your DNS configuration is wrong.

**How have you done that configuration?**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/281395)

Comment: @G-Man I would have liked to rather comment as well but at my reputation level it is not possible as you stated. I just wanted to help anyway. If the asker answers my question I can edit my answer to be complete.

Comment: @majesticLSD : Note that G-Man's comment is generate from reviewing tool. We appreciate you try to help/calrify question. You can get early reputation by giving answer, fixing typos/formating in answers.